# Why output other date?

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

i have this code

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
     try{
        java.util.Date mDate;
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat readFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        mDate = readFormat.parse("2017-02-05");
        System.out.println("date: " + mDate.toString());
     } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

}

i expected output like Feb 05 00:02:00 UTC 2017

but im getting output Jan 05 00:02:00 UTC 2017  why? what's wrong in my code?

[image]

Comment: System.out.println("date: " + readFormat.format( mDate);

Comment: mm vs MM ......

Comment: but why the output said January instead feb??? the string date is 2017-02-05 and the output its like 2017-01-05

Comment: @Selvin I think the question is rather why `readFormat.parse("2017-02-05")` ends up in January.

Comment: @Axel yeah ... That's why there is a new comment

Comment: @Axel, probably because `Jan` is a first month in year in Gregorian Calendar, and is default value for any parsed date as a result.

Comment: Well, the question is actually: why is OP unwilling to read the documentation when he don't know the correct pattern?

Comment: ty with MM instead mm i get the correct date ty @Selvin

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoBlancoVivas Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This issue has been addressed *many* times already. Most any basic date-time issue has already been asked and answered. If you'd searched you would have found many examples of code you could have compared to yours to discover the problem of `MM` vs `mm`.

Answer (score 4):

When you create this format: `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")`, that means

1. 4-digit year
2. 2-digit minute in hour
3. 2-digit day in month

So "2017-02-05" is two minutes into the 5th day of 2017, and that's 5 of january.

You should use `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).